# Test for significant population change in before-and-after study?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have the following dataset from a before-and-after study which shows population counts of five species of liverworts during two sample periods (the years 2013 and 2017). I wish to test whether there has been a significant change in the population counts between the sample periods. What is the most appropriate statistical test please?

Species, 2013, 2017
Aphanolejeunea microscopica, 37, 39
Drepanolejeunea hamatifolia, 69, 65
Harpalejeunea molleri, 48, 38
Jubula hutchinsiae, 111, 114
Radula voluta, 13, 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two clarifications:

1) You cannot statistically test for a difference in any one species, because you have just two measurements. But you can test for an overall difference across all species.

2) You have very little data to work with, so you shouldn't expect to have much power to test for anything.

That said, you can compare the overall population differences between 2013 and 2017 using a **paired *t*-test**. You can do this using the `t.test` function in `R` with the argument `paired = TRUE`.

This is how you would do the analysis in R:

```
 population_2013 = c(37, 69, 48, 111, 13)

 population_2017 = c(39, 65, 38, 114, 6)

 t.test(population_2013, population_2017, paired = TRUE)
```

And your results are:

```
    Paired t-test

 data:  population_2013 and population_2017 

 t = 1.2709, df = 4, p-value = 0.2727 

 alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0  

 95 percent confidence interval:  -3.79091 10.19091 

 sample estimates: mean of the differences 

                     3.2
```

As expected based on the small sample size, your difference is non-significant.